# API Documentation for ScopeMaster Plugin via Jira

Tags: plugins, jira

I am new to the Jira environment and I am currently doing research for ScopeMaster which is needed to use in Jira. I installed the ScopeMaster plugin in Jira. I can see a story analyzer in the user story. But I wanted to know the API calls related to ScopeMaster via Jira. Is there any API documentation available for the ScopeMaster via Jira? Only I was able to find ScopeMaster related API as mentioned below not related to Jira.
ScopeMaster API - https://help.scopemaster.com/article/46-apps

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.atlassian.com/server/framework/atlassian-sdk/using-the-rest-api-browser/ is the way I explore the REST APIs of plugins. Make sure to uncheck the Public checkbox. You can also use the Network tab in the Chrome Inspector to see what is called. And contact the plugin vendor to ask for any info they are willing to make public

Answer (score 0):

You can use ScopeMaster without using the "Jira plugin".  It's available as a SaaS from Scopemaster.com

Scopemaster has a REST API that can be use without Jira but you must first have a registered account to use the Saas.

The "Jira Plugin" aka Story Analyser for Jira (from Scopemaster) offers a subset of the functionality available from the Saas.  It conforms to the Jira Connect App construction and security guidelines.

I hope that clarifies for you.  Colin (Scopemaster author).